# shared_ptr in std::tr1

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, shared-ptr, tr1

I am working on a platform with a gcc compiler however boost cannot compile on it.

I am wondering what is the proper way to include the shared_ptr in std:tr1 on gcc? the file i looked in said not to include it directly, from what i can tell no other file includes it either :|

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In **G++ 4.3**,

```
#include <tr1/memory>
```

should do the trick. You'll find `shared_ptr` at `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost itself has the answer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/usage.html#boost_tr1.usage.include_style).

Answer (score 3):

Boost can not compile on it? Most of the boost library doesn't need to be compiled to be used, and I guess shared_ptr doesn't either.