# the program does not recognize smart pointer

Tags: c++, syntax, std, shared-ptr

Regarding the use of shared_pointers in a c++ program, I have declared the `#include <memory>`
and then called upon the following `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(5))` it refuses to compile saying that

> error: 'shared_ptr' is not a member of 'std'

or alternatively

> Symbol 'shared_ptr' could not be resolved

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? from what i read, shared point should be defined in std or boost  libraries and i have tried them both

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is part of C++11.  If you are using an older version of C++, you can use `boost::shared_ptr`

Comment: What compiler are you using? If its `g++` did you add `-std=c++11`?

Comment: did you try including tr1/memory? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471438/shared-ptr-in-stdtr1

Answer (score 4):

[`std::shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a C++11 feature.

You must have a compiler supporting this.

For example with GCC you should add `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`.

If you don't have C++11, you can also use [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: I tried doing that - doesn't work with the error "Symbol 'shared_ptr' could not be resolved "

Comment: @NoamFisher What is your compiler? [**example**](http://ideone.com/e7ekSm) with gcc v4.8.1.

Comment: thanks for the help. This was the question I as looking for. also had  to update the CDT.                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312854/eclipse-indexer-cant-resolve-shared-ptr